# Retorno outerHTML dos elementos

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo uma biblioteca baseado em minhas necessidades. Digamos que no exemplo abaixo:

```
lib('#menu a').html()
```

Retorna tranquilo o `outerHTML`, como mostra abaixo:

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
```

Caso o seletor `('#menu a')` possuir mais de uma tag "**a**", como fazer para retornar todos os `outerHTML`:

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você pode fazer o seguinte:

```js
var menus = document.querySelectorAll("#menu a");
var outerHTML = [].map.call(menus, function(menu) {
    return menu.outerHTML;
}).join("\n");

var textarea = document.getElementById("outerHTML");
textarea.value = outerHTML;
```

```css
#outerHTML{
  width: 260px;
  height: 51px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<textarea id="outerHTML"></textarea>
```

Comment: Obrigado, @Paulo Rodrigues... perfeito.

Answer (score 2):

Está resposta é apenas complementar, o [exemplo do @TobyMosque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56605/3635) é muito bom, porém o uso do `element.outerHTML` não é *cross-platform* (acredito que a maioria dos motores hoje suportem, mas ainda podem haver casos que não suportam), para resolver isto podemos fazer um método alternativo, seria clonar o elemento que quer obter o `outerHTML` e adicionar ele a um elemento criado por `document.createElement`, exemplo:

```js
var texto = document.getElementById("texto");

document.getElementById("run").onclick = function() {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("test");
    var elementoVazio = document.createElement("div");

    elementoVazio.appendChild(elemento.cloneNode(true));
    texto.value = elementoVazio.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"><strong>Olá mundo!</strong></div>
<p>
  <a id="run" href="#">Pegar outerHTML</a>
</p>
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="texto"></textarea>
```

Podemos adicionar este método como uma alternativa e se o navegador der suporte ao `outerHTML` não irá usar ele, pois não tem necessidade, para resolvermos podemos usar o código a seguir:

```
var divTmp = document.createElement("div");
if ("outerHTML" in divTmp) {
  //Código com outerHTML nativo
  ...
} else {
   //Código com cloneNode()
  ...
}
```

O código ficaria algo como:

```js
var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
var divTmp = document.createElement("div");

document.getElementById("run").onclick = function() {
    var elementoVazio, elemento = document.getElementById("test");

    if ("outerHTML" in divTmp) {
        texto.value = elemento.outerHTML;
    } else {
        elementoVazio = document.createElement("div");
        elementoVazio.appendChild(elemento.cloneNode(true));
        texto.value = elementoVazio.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"><strong>Olá mundo!</strong></div>
<p>
  <a id="run" href="#">Pegar outerHTML</a>
</p>
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="texto"></textarea>
```

O código do TobyMosque ficaria algo como:

```
if ("outerHTML" in divTmp) {
  function getOuterHTML(menu) {
    return menu.outerHTML;
  }
} else {
  function getOuterHTML(menu) {
    var data, el = document.createElement("div");

    el.appendChild(menu.cloneNode(true));
    data = el.innerHTML;
    el = null;

    return data;
  }
}

var menus = document.querySelectorAll("#menu a");
var outerHTML = [].map.call(menus, getOuterHTML).join("\n");
```

Comment: Não acredito que a compatibilidade do outerHTML seja um problema, ele é implementado pelo IE4, Safari 1.3 e Chrome 0.2, que são bem antigos, talvez a unica resalva aqui seja o Firefox que só adicionou suporte ao outerHTML em 2012, porém é muito mais facil encontrar um IE desatualizado que um firefox. por um outro lado, o método map requer mais cuidado, pois apenas o IE9+ implenta o mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado a todos...